# Node Module import error for exceljs-Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'TypedArray'

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, package.json, exceljs

After implementing exceljs functionality I ran `npm install` and tried to run the app using `ng serve` and I am getting the below error.

```
ERROR in node_modules/exceljs/index.d.ts: - error TS2694: Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'TypedArray'.

dictionary: Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView | ArrayBuffer; // deflate/inflate only, empty dictionary by default
```

Can someone help me to fix this.

Comment: This discussion might help you: [Namespace 'NodeJS' has no exported member 'TypedArray'](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1015). Also would be helpful if you post your angular and npm version etc.

Comment: I have tried the solutions from that discussion and nothing helped.
npm-6.14.6 , angular 10.1.2 and Node: 12.18.3.